# How combine the temporary link with the real link on Django 2.2

Tags: django

I ran into such a problem. I created temporary links on the site. I can’t combine the temporary link with the real link (video link). How is this possible? So that a person can access the video only through a temporary link.
with this code https://dpaste.de/uivr

Comment: please cost the code that you are referring to.

Comment: @Caleb Goodman Here is my code https://dpaste.de/uivr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can check out this pypi package [django-onetimelink](https://pypi.org/project/django-onetimelink/). It could be used to generate one-time link of an uploaded file. And It can create a site with one-time links of all the files uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

I see my influence there from a past question on here (this isn't an accusation, go ahead and use the code).

I am not completely clear about what you are looking for, but I assume that you are seeking to somehow host a file at one link, but only allow access to that link through the temporary link.

Here is what I came up with:

**models.py**

```
class OneTimeLink(models.Model):
    one_time_code = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    expiry_time = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now()+timedelta(hours=1), blank=True)
    video_code = models.CharField(max_length=250, default="XBRSJFLA")

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.expiry_time}"

class VideoLink(models.Model):
    url = models.CharField(max_length=250, default="THEVIDEOURL")
    pass_code = models.CharField(max_length=250, default="XBRSJFLA")
```

I created a separate video link model to handle ensuring that the person cannot return to the video URL later (i.e. it only works once). `url` is the link to the video and `pass_code` is meant to match with the `video_code`  in `OneTimeLink`.

**views.py**

```
def randomString(stringLength=20):
    """Generate a random string of fixed length """
    letters = string.ascii_lowercase
    return ''.join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(stringLength))

def generate_link(request):
    the_string = randomString(stringLength=20)
    OneTimeLink.objects.create(one_time_code=the_string)
    url = '<a href="/polls/one_time_link/{}">{}{}</a>'.format(the_string, request.build_absolute_uri(), the_string)
    return HttpResponse(url)
```

The above code is what you have seen already. It generates a random string for the temporary link (as well as the temporary url for the video now) as well as the temporary link itself.

```
def one_time_link(request, access_code=0):
    if OneTimeLink.objects.filter(one_time_code=access_code).exists():
        obj = OneTimeLink.objects.get(one_time_code=access_code)
        field_object = OneTimeLink._meta.get_field('expiry_time')
        expiry_time = field_object.value_from_object(obj)
        if expiry_time < datetime.now(timezone.utc):
            #remove the line below if you do not want the link to self destruct after it has been used
            OneTimeLink.objects.filter(one_time_code=access_code).delete()
            video_var = VideoLink.objects.get(pass_code=obj.video_code)
            the_url = video_var.url
            return redirect('video_link',the_url)
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Bad or expired link.")
    elif not OneTimeLink.objects.filter(one_time_code=access_code).exists():
        return HttpResponse("Bad or expired link.")
    else:
        return HttpResponse("Bad or expired link.")
```

This code does the same as your existing `one_time_link`, except that instead of the `HttpResponse`, it obtains the `url` for the relevant video and redirects to that url. It goes to `video_link`, along with the url stored in the video link.

```
def video_link(request, video_code):
    if VideoLink.objects.filter(url=video_code).exists():
        video_var = VideoLink.objects.get(url=video_code)
        video_var.url = randomString(stringLength=10)
        video_var.save()
        return HttpResponse("Here is your video. You can only access this with the link.")
    else:
        return HttpResponse("Nope. no video here. Go pay for it you thief!")
```

This is the video link url generator. It takes the `video_code` as the argument and checks for a `url` in `VideoLink` which matches. If it finds that the link is still valid, it changes the URL so it cannot be used again and serves the relevant content.

**urls.py**

```
    path('one_time_link/<str:access_code>', views.one_time_link, name='one_time_link'),
    path('video_link/<str:video_code>', views.video_link, name='video_link'),
```

Just what the urls are in case you run into trouble. This entire thing should be a working example so long as you go into the Django Admin and create the first `VideoLink` object.

Comment: Ok but it is doesn't work for me i want to generate a new link for the video. This code generate new link but i can't use this it removes the original link.

Comment: Would it work if it just didn't remove the original link?

Comment: Maybe I’m explaining it wrong. I have a link to the video, I want it not to be visible but to be hidden and a one-time link like https://streamguard.cc/video/2a737de88557d0a1/iframe
This is a link to a one-shot video. If you go through it, it no longer works. But this code to only links. And i need combine the temporary link with the real link

Comment: Couldn't you add a third item to VideoLink for the url of the file and serve the file through the temporary generated url? Would that not meet your needs?